# Change value of array item when sorting

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am writing some tests that need to check the sort order of an ng-grid table. I get some values back from an API call that is then put into a table, the sorting on the table allows to sort ascending and descending as expected but 'Not Set' is always shown at either the very top or very bottom of the table.

My protractor test grabs the text value of the items in the list then I grab the items from the API response as an array and sort using JavaScript to check that the sorting is working, but obviously 'N' isn't higher than 'A' in the alphabet, is there a way to make it so that when i sort using JavaScript 'Not Set' always goes to the top of the list?

I'v had a search on Google but i cant find anything but maybe I'm using the wrong search terms

Comment: Could you show some code?